# Run script every 2 hours, 6 times in X pattern, 6 times in Y pattern per 24 hours

Tags: php

I want to run a script every two hours, so I use this cron jon command:

`0  */2 *   *   *`

The script should use key X when running the first time, and on the following run it should use key Y, and then X again and so on.

My initial idea was to use the server time, and according to whether the hour is odd or even number, it will choose different key:

```
$h = date('G');

if ( $h & 1 ) {  
$key = "X"; } // odd
else { 
$key = "Y"; } // even
```

But since I run it every two hours in the first place, it is bound to use only one of these keys always, so it's not good.

What's a good way to achieve this?

Comment: How about two separate cron statements running on alternating hours, and pass a different argument from each one?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a file "flag.txt" to filesystem, and check if he exists. If it exists, use X and delete file, if it not exists, create file and use Y.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this should work, but I have no tested it. But doing this with date is the easiest to do.
1 to 12 with date

```
$dDate = date("g");
```

Lets say that it fires on 0/2/4/6/8/10/12

```
$iResult = $dDate % 2;
```

If any of the given fire times is given $iResult will be 0 so in this case

```
if($iResult != 0) {
    //Do X
} else {
    //Do Y
}
```